# 3d graphics java restricted acces

Tags: java, package, java-3d

I wanted to learn Java 3d-graphics, so i needed the `com.sun.j3d.utils` package.
They said I had to download it, but i first tried if Eclipse's autocompletion would recognize it, I thought that would mean it was installed already.
When I started typing the import line, everything went well, but when I added the last piece: `.universe.SimpleUniverse;` Eclipse came up with it's red underlining. Then, I copy-pasted the complete class from the tutorial (http://www.java3d.org/starting.html) to read the error message left of the linenumbers.
They said this on the first import line:
Access restriction: The type SimpleUniverse is not accessible due to restriction on required library /System/Library/Java/Extensions/j3dutils.jar

The error messages on the other import lines were the same, accept for the .jar filename. In the constructor it says something about acces restrictions too. Im working with Mac OS X and Eclipse (or XCode).
How can I fix this? I am the administrator of the computer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isssue which arose in Eclipse 3.6.1 should have been solved in later releases. See https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2133747&tstart=30